# Combine similar rows to create a time series

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to manipulate some data to show a time series of cars using R. I want to plot the speed of each car over the time series. I would like it to look like the image below. With each line representing the different cars.

```
Cars    Date    Speed
Yellow Car  2017-07-02 17:41:00 20
Green car   2017-07-08 05:01:35 30
Yellow Car  2017-07-08 05:03:31 10
Blue Car    2017-07-08 05:52:55 4
Green car   2017-07-08 10:21:57 2
Green car   2017-07-08 12:07:51 12
```

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset is not complete but you can get the idea from the example below:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Time, y=Speed, group=Cars, color=Cars)) + geom_line() + 
              scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue", "green", "yellow"))
```

[image]

***Data:***

This is not the same as your data (it has different columns), but looks like it.

```
df <- structure(list(Cars = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("BlueCar", 
"Greencar", "YellowCar"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2017-07-08", "207-07-08"), class = "factor"), 
Time = structure(c(6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("05:01:35", 
"05:03:31", "05:52:55", "10:21:57", "12:07:51", "17:41:00"
), class = "factor"), Speed = c(20L, 30L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 15L)),
.Names = c("Cars", "Date", "Time", "Speed"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))
```

Comment: Dude this was awesome help! One other question, what if I wanted to represent date and time within the x axis. I stumbled upon as.POSIXlt which seems to take this UTC format, how would I implement it here?

Comment: @AnthonyM add this `+ scale_x_datetime(breaks = Date, labels = format(Date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`